# Change T-SQL Query to SAP HANA

Tags: sql, hana

I will be glad if someone can convert this T-SQL query into SAP HANA completely.

What I am trying to do is autonumbering query that has a prefix of PV plus 6 numbers. eg pv000001. I have it in T-SQL but I am having a challenge to change it to SAP HANA completely;

```
DECLARE @NumRange integer;
SET @NumRange := 6;
SELECT 'PV' || replicate('0', @NumRange - LENGTH(MAX(ISNULL(Incnum, 0)))) || CAST(MAX(ISNULL(Incnum, 0)) + 1 AS varchar(6)) 
FROM (
   SELECT MAX(coalesce(substring(CounterRef, 3, LENGTH(ISNULL(CounterRef, 0))), 0)) AS "incnum" 
   FROM OVPM T0 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT MAX(coalesce(substring(CounterRef, 3, LENGTH(ISNULL(CounterRef, 0))), 0)) AS "incnum" 
   FROM OPDF T0 WHERE t0.ObjType = '46'
) AS Tb1;
```

Comment: [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Can't you simply use `row_number()` to generate the numbers?

Answer (score 0):

This is the query converted to HANA SQLScript and tweaked a bit to make it work in my SAP Business One database:

```
DO BEGIN
    DECLARE NumRange INTEGER;
    NumRange := 6;

    SELECT 'PV' || REPLICATE('0', :NumRange - LENGTH(MAX(IFNULL("Incnum", 0)))) || CAST(MAX(IFNULL("Incnum", 0)) + 1 AS VARCHAR(6))
    FROM (
        SELECT MAX(coalesce(substring("CounterRef", 3, LENGTH(IFNULL("CounterRef", 0))), 0)) AS "Incnum"
        FROM OVPM T0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT MAX(coalesce(substring("CounterRef", 3, LENGTH(IFNULL("CounterRef", 0))), 0)) AS "Incnum"
        FROM OPDF T0
        WHERE t0."ObjType" = '46'
    ) AS Tb1;
END;
```

HANA does not have a REPLICATE function, but you can create your own:

```
CREATE FUNCTION REPLICATE(input NVARCHAR(1000), count INT)
RETURNS output NVARCHAR(1000)
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT = 1;
    output := '';
    FOR i IN 1 .. count DO
        output := output || input;
    END FOR;
END;
```

**Some explanations:**

- HANA allows SQL Script (DECLARE, FOR, etc.) only inside of blocks,
  which is why I wrapped the first statement inside of an anonymous [DO
  BEGIN END](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/52/103853351841f6a1e87f40b2686da9/content.htm) block.
- HANA is case-sensitive, therefore I had to change the different casing of Incnum/incnum.
- You *write* to variables just by using their name, you *read* from them by prepending them with a colon (:).

Comment: After creating the function and running the query i get the below error;

Comment: @JusticeDoku You have not added a "below error". The query works for me on a fresh company database on SAP Business One 9.2 PL04.

Comment: Hi Hannobo, I tried pasting the error here but I was prompted my values exceed 290 messages. But I will be glad if you can share with me a screenshot on how you applied the queries in SAP Business One version for HANA 9.2 PL 04.  Do I have to run the function in HANA studio and apply the above query in the SAP Business One  User defined field??

Answer (score 0):

just a quick note on REPLICATE function in HANA

We don't have a SQLScript Replicate function, but LPAD string function can be used in many cases

For example, if in SQL Server T-SQL we have:

```
select REPLICATE('0',4)
```

In SAP HANA database, in SQLScript we can get the same result as follows:

```
select LPAD('',4,'0') as str from DUMMY;
```

Of course if the replicated string is more than a single character, then the output results will differ